# Difference between two consecutive windows

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka-stream application, that counts the number of impressions for each product we sell on our site (product_id is the event's key).
I use a hopping window, with 1-hour window and 10-minutes "hop". I also use the suppress functionality so 1 aggregation per key is being sent at the end of each window.

My question is - 
Suppose that "product-1" got X impressions between [1:00, 2:00), but  got no impressions for [1:10, 2:10) window. The last message my Kafka-streams app will publish for "product-1" is "X impressions" at the end of [1:00,2:00) window. This state will be stuck forever (on the client-side, who consume this aggregation data) until "product-1" will get an impression somewhere in the future and a new aggregation event will be sent.

I would like to send a message, at the end of [1:10,2:10), saying "no impressions for product-1". And if we will zoom out, I would like, at the end of each window, to find the diff between the current window's keys to the previous one. That way, I could send "reset" events for those product keys.

If I could get an indication that a window has been closed and all aggregation results were sent, I could have calculated this diff.

Anyone who faced a similar issue?

Comment: Hi Simon! Did you manage to find a solution for your use case?